# Java arraycopy Method

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayCoping {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Copied from Java Docs
    char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
    char[] copyTo = new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
    System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    //Experimenting
    System.out.println("Printing char: " + new String(copyTo));
    System.out.println("Printing char: " + (copyTo));
    System.out.println(copyTo);

    // STRING
    String[] stringSrc = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr" };
    String[] stringDst = new String[4];
    System.arraycopy(stringSrc, 1, stringDst, 0, 4);
//Error     System.out.println(new String(stringDst));
    System.out.println("Printing string: " + (stringDst));
    System.out.println(stringDst);

    // INT
    int[] numSrc = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    int[] numDst = new int[4];
    System.arraycopy(numSrc, 1, numDst, 0, 4);
//Error     System.out.println(new int (numDst));
    System.out.println("Printing int: " + (numDst));
    System.out.println(numDst);
}
```

}
1. Can you please explain why the same code block isn't working for different primitive types (working with char but not with int and String). `System.out.println(new String(copyTo));` works with **char** but not with **String**. Similarly `System.out.println(copyTo);`working for **char** but not with **String** and **int**.

2. Why same primitive type behaves differently with same code? `System.out.println("Printing char: " + (copyTo));` doesn't works but `System.out.println(copyTo);`

I didn't find any material which says `arraycopy` method works with **char** data type only.

Comment: I can't understand your question. What exactly is the problem? Please make a _minimal_ example with one question. It seems like there are at least 3 or 4 questions here.

Comment: `//Error     System.out.println(new String(stringDst));` .. because you have to parse `String` and not `String[]`

Comment: _arraycopy_ method isn't working with **int** and **String**.

Comment: ```String``` is not a primitive type btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just printing the results wrong.

```
System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
```

Just happens to work because `String` has a constructor that takes a `char[]`.

If you want to print arrays, use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringDst));
...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numDst));
```